# How can I replace a checkbox with a <select> in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

My code is set up to allow a user to select a sort direction:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="row in gdata | orderBy:inverse">
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="orderby">
   <div class="arrow up"></div>
   <div class="arrow down"></div>
   <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="inverse">
</div>
```

How can I replace this with a  in Angular? So far I have coded this:

```
   <select data-ng-model="inverse">
      <option value="??">Sort Up</option>
      <option value="??">Sort Down</option>
   </select>
```

Can someone tell me am I doing it the right way and how can I set the values ?

Answer (score 0):

Alot depends on the data you are using, and how you want the user to sort, but I created a basic example in this jsFiddle that you can play around with: http://jsfiddle.net/xRkhc/2/

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="row in gdata | orderBy:sort">
      {{row.model}}
  </div>        

  <select ng-model="sort">
    <option value="model">Sort Up by Model</option>
    <option value="-model">Sort Down by Model</option>
    <option value="topSpeed">Sort Up by TopSpeed</option>
    <option value="-topSpeed">Sort Down by TopSpeed</option>
  </select>    
</div>
```

Controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.sort = "model"; //just to set the default sort in the dropdown, not required
    $scope.gdata = [{'model':'M3','topSpeed':'200'},{'model':'Type R','topSpeed':'150'}, {'model':'S2000','topSpeed':'160'},{'model':'NSX','topSpeed':'180'}];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you hardcode the options (as in your code) the model only receives strings or numbers, you must use `ng-options` (or it's equivalent `data-ng-options`) instead of hardcoding the options. You specify the options as a member of your model.

Here's a complete example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html data-ng-app>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var exampleCtrl = function ($scope) {
      $scope.sortingDirection = {
      'Sort Up'   :   true,
      'Sort Down' :   false
  };
  $scope.inverse = true;
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-ng-controller="exampleCtrl">
        <select data-ng-model="inverse" data-ng-options="value as key for (key, value) in sortingDirection">
        </select>
        <pre data-ng-bind="inverse | json"></pre>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain what's happening with "inverse | json"  I don't understand what that's there for. Thanks

Comment: The `| json` part is an [AngularJS filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter) being applied to `inverse`. It's just for visualization purposes. In this case, I used it to show that the value assigned to `inverse` is actually a boolean `true` or `false` instead of the strings`"true"` or `"false"`.